# Как расположить элемент в самый низ при значении родителя 100vh

Tags: html, css

У меня есть родитель который занимает всю высоты экрана (100vh) и у меня есть картинка которая должна быть в самом низу, какие значения нужно задать, чтобы картинка была в самом низу при все том же значении 100vh у родителя

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.vh{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
}
.bottom-child{
  width: 200px;
  height: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="vh">
  <div class="bottom-child"></div>
  <!-- <img class="bottom-child" src="..." alt=""> -->
</div>
```